# Datasets for custom size sudoku puzzles

Tags: data-request

I have found tons of datasets for 9x9 sudoku puzzles, though couldn't find custom size puzzles (e.g block size of 2x5 and board size of 10x10, block size of 7x3 and board size of 21x21).

Any clue on how to find (puzzles or generating algorithms) and (solutions or solver algorithms)?